# Substring js in php

Tags: javascript, php, substring, imdb

enter code here
I'm trying to get out ID from link:

```
www.imdb.com/title/tt5807628/   - >  tt5807628
```

My code in javascript:

```
  var str = "www.imdb.com/title/tt5807628/";
  var n = str.search("e/tt");
  var res = str.substring(n+2, n+30);
  var ukos = res.search("/");
  var last = res.substring(0, ukos);
```

I would like to get the same effect in PHP, how to do it?

Comment: `$id = explode("/", "www.imdb.com/title/tt5807628/")[2];` -> `tt5807628`

Comment: wow :o Thank you!

Comment: If I or another answer helped you, consider up-voting and marking an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400716/substring-js-in-php?noredirect=1#comment81755067_47400716), the following code will just give you the ID:

```
$id = explode("/", "www.imdb.com/title/tt5807628/")[2];
```

We use the [`explode(delimiter, string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function here to break the string at each of the slashes, which creates an index of strings that looks like this:

```
array (
    0 => "www.imdb.com"
    1 => "title"
    2 => "tt5707627"
)
```

So, as you can see array index `2` is our ID, so we select that after we break the string (which is the `[2]` at the end of the variable declaration), leaving us with a variable `$id` that contains just the ID from the link.

---

**edit:**

> You could also use parse_url before the explode, just to ensure that
>   you dont run into http(s):// if the link changes due to user input.
>   - [Keja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3774580/keja)

```
$id = explode("/", parse_url("www.imdb.com/title/tt5807628/", PHP_URL_PATH))[2];
```

Comment: You could also use parse_url before the explode, just to ensure that you dont run into http(s):// if the link changes due to user input. `$id = explode("/", parse_url("www.imdb.com/title/tt5807628/", PHP_URL_PATH))[2];`

Answer (score 0):

With explode function then you can see each part by looping through the array

```
$varArray = explode( '/', $var );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as well:

```
preg_match('~www\.imdb\.com/title/([^/]*)/~', 'www.imdb.com/title/tt5807628/', $matches);

$id = $matches[1];
```